# Sympy не видит IronPython 2.7.5

Tags: c#, ironpython, sympy

Нужно запустить код питона в c#, а именно использовать библиотеку sympy, нашел топик, который отвечает на мой вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721736/c-sharp-library-for-algebra-simplification-and-solving . В ответе, который дал Damon Achey 2-ым пунктом идет установка sympy.exe, но в этом вся и проблема, при попытке установки sympy дает ошибку

> no python installation found in the registry

Немного поискав в гугле решение данной проблемы нашел несколько ответов :

1. Питон не в ту ветку регистра записал данные (записал в `HKLM\SOFTWARE\` , а нужно в `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\`), у меня с этим проблем нет, после установки папка есть в `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\`.
2. Питон записал в ветку `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (тобишь, только для данного юзера), а нужно `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, как вы уже догадались, у меня записано в `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` , хотя и в `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` есть запись

Можете помочь решить проблему ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попытался воспроизвести и получил тот же самый результат. Детально разбираться в чем причина не стал, возможно у вас система другой архитектуры.

Поэтому поступил "по старинке":

1. Установил [IronPython](http://ironpython.net)
2. Собрал из исходников [mpmath](http://mpmath.org)
3. Собрал из исходников [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html)

---

Запустил пример:

1. Создал проект консольного приложения
2. Добавил NuGet - пакет: `Install-Package IronPython`
3. Перевел [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721736/c-sharp-library-for-algebra-simplification-and-solving) из вопроса на SO по вашей ссылке на F#

---

```
open IronPython.Hosting

let options = ["FullFrames", true :> obj] |> dict

let engine = Python.CreateEngine options

let paths = engine.GetSearchPaths()
paths.Add @"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib"
engine.SetSearchPaths paths

// expression to simplify
let expr = "0 + 1 * 1 * (x - 2) / (1 - 2) * (x - 3) / (1 - 3) * (x - 4) / (1 - 4)";

let scope = engine.CreateScope()
let script = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(@"
import codecs
def my_unicode_escape_decode(x):
    return x
codecs.unicode_escape_decode = my_unicode_escape_decode

from sympy import *
import clr
from System import String

expr = simplify('" + expr + @"')
result = clr.Convert(expr, String)
")

script.Execute scope |> ignore

scope.GetVariable "result" |> printfn "%A"
```

---

Мне пришлось изменить код, чтобы заставить его работать, но возможно у вас питон проглотит и исходную версию.

Ваша коллекция `paths` может отличатся - для удобства я скопировал установленные библиотеки туда, где находится IronPython.

---

Если будут падать какие-то исключения - пингуйте меня в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50036/f)